# How to execute fadein() and fadeout() ONLY ONCE, in a loop and setInterval?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making a listing system that updates, checking new data from a JSON file every 3 seconds. Also I am adding effects fadeIn() and fadeOut() but 
the fadeIn() and fadeOut() are executing everytime it loops and (setInterval(list, 3000);). **i want to execute it once the data is already appended**. sorry for my bad english.

Note: **IT KEEPS ON BLINKING. in 3 seconds**

```
list();
setInterval(list, 3000);

function list() {
    $.getJSON('list.php',function(response){
        var timeout = 400;
        $("#list").fadeOut(timeout);
        $('#list').fadeIn(timeout);
        $('#list').empty();

        for(var i = 0; i < response.list_count; i++){
            var newElement = document.createElement('div');
            newElement.innerHTML = response.list[i].firstname;
            document.getElementById("list").appendChild(newElement);
        }
        document.getElementById("list_count").innerHTML = "" +  response.list_count; + ""; 
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

try adding variable and assign true if your element is showed (just for checker if element is already showed)

```
var displayed = false;

list();
setInterval(list, 3000);

function list() {
    $.getJSON('list.php',function(response){
        var timeout = 400;
        if (displayed == false) {
            $("#list").fadeOut(timeout);
            $('#list').fadeIn(timeout);
            displayed = true;
        }
        $('#list').empty();

        for(var i = 0; i < response.list_count; i++){
            var newElement = document.createElement('div');
            newElement.innerHTML = response.list[i].firstname;
            document.getElementById("list").appendChild(newElement);
        }
        document.getElementById("list_count").innerHTML = "" +  response.list_count; + ""; 
    });
};
```